# Check null value in a list using linq

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list `List<OfferComparison> Comparison`. I want to 
check if all the items have `Value == null` in an `if` condition.

How can I do it with linq?

```
public class OfferComparison : BaseModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool Valid { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Worth bookmarking - https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Updated (post C# 7) Answer**

If using C# 7 or 8 then one could use the `is` keyword together with `Linq.All`:

```
var result = Comparison.All(item => item.Value is null)
```

If using C# 9 then one could use the `is not null` together with `Linq.Any`:

```
var result = Comparison.Any(item => item.Value is not null)
```

If using C# 9 then one could also use the `is object` or `is {}` together with `Linq.Any`:

```
var result = Comparison.Any(item => item.Value is object)
```

All these options are somewhat equivalent. At least in terms of time complexity they are all `O(n)`. I guess the "preferred" option simply depends on personal opinion.

---

**Original (pre C# 7) Answer**

Using linq method of [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = Comparison.All(item => item.Value == null)
```

Basically what it does is to iterate all items of a collection and check a predicate for each of them. If one does not match - result is false

---

Answer (score 4):

You can check by this linq statement

```
var isNull = Comparison.All(item => item.Value == null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure about the internal differences of `All` and `Exists`, but it might be a good idea to just check whether one of the entries is not null and then negate the result:

```
var result = !Comparison.Exists(o => o.Value != null);
```

I would expect this query to quit after the first non-null value was found and therefore to be a little more efficient.

**Update:** From the [Enumerable.All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined.

Therefore, using `All` will probably not result in the entire list getting processed after a non-null value has been found.

So the aforementioned possible performance gain is not likely to occur and both solutions probably do not differ.